# Will memmove function share the same address as the temporary pointer?

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, memmove

Suppose there is pointer to an array of float values: `float *source;` and we know its size as `int sourcesize;`

There is an already implemented function which add an element to the `souce` array from the `inputVec`:

```
void addRecord(const float* inputVec, int& sourcesize)
{
   int inputVecSize = sourcesize;
   memmove( (float*)&(source[inputVecSize]), inputVec, sizeof(float));
}
```

Now, I want to copy 1 element from the `m`th element of the source array and attach it to the source end. By using the addRecord above, I have implemented a function as below:

```
// suppose m is smaller than the current sourcesize
void copyRecord(const float* source, int& m)
{
    float* temporary = new float;
    memcpy( temporary, (float*)&(source[m]), sizeof(float));
    addRecord(temporary, sourcesize);
    delete temporary;
}
```

It seems the `memmove` call in the `addRecord` function may share the variable location of temporary. Thus, maybe I should not delete `temporary` in the end. But I think maybe they do not share the same address, then I should delete `temporary` in this case.

So, should I delete `temporary` in the end or not?

Or, is there a better way to copy an element from `source` array to its end by using function `addRecord`?

Comment: This code has no hope of working if you're copying `m` floats to an arbitrary single float. I'd strongly encourage you to use Standard Library containers like `std::vector` to store this data.

Comment: `sizeof(JtFloat32)` and `sizeof(float)` may not be the same - else why have `JtFloat32`? If they differ, `float* temporary = new float;
    memcpy( temporary, (JtFloat32*)&(source[m]), sizeof(JtFloat32));` is trouble.

Comment: You need `JtFloat32* temporary = new JtFloat32[m]` at the *absolute least*. You should also change the method signature to `JtFloat32*` to avoid casting.

Comment: What is `size`, should that be `sourcesize`?

Comment: changed my errors

Answer (score 1):

`memmove()` copies the *contents* of the memory that `temporary` points to. That copy is not dependent on the original `temporary`, so it's perfectly safe to delete it after calling `memmove()`.

But there's no need for the temporary in the first place, you can copy directly from the original array.

```
addRecord(&(source[m]), sizeof source[m]);
```